# Integer rings and UFDs in transcendental field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, transcendental-numbers, unique-factorization-domains, integer-rings

I recently began to study algebraic field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ aka number fields and especially the definition of algebraic integers in these fields. Some rings of algebraic integers are unique factorization domains (UFDs) e.g. $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Z} \left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-19}}{2} \right]$ whereas others are not e.g. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

In example 2.14 of Frazer Jarvis' book *Algebraic number theory* it is stated that:

> 6. $\mathbb{Q(π)}$ is not a number field; $\pi$ does not satisfy any polynomial equation over $\mathbb{Q}$ (as it is transcendental); therefore $[\mathbb{Q}(π) : \mathbb{Q}]$ is infinite.

An integer in a number field of degree $n$ is defined as a root of some polynomial $X^n + a_1 X^{n-1} + \dots + a_n$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. But as the degree of a transcendental extension is infinite, it seems to me that this definition does not seem viable for these field.

This makes me wonder whether there is actually a way to define transcendental integers in the field $\mathbb{Q(π)}$ and other transcendental extensions such that this set forms a ring under the usual arithmetic operations. If so, does the ring of integers have an integral basis and can it be shown to be a UFD in some cases?

Also can you recommend any book to dive deeper into the theory of transcendental field extensions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can define integral elements over $\Bbb Q[\pi]$, which is nothing but $\Bbb Q[X]$, the polynomial ring over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: This was my initial idea, too. We have $\mathbb{Z}[\pi] \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and apparently every polynomial ring with coefficients in R is a UFD when R is a UFD. But is this the usual way of defining integers in transcendental field extensions?

Comment: For a finite extension $K/\Bbb{Q}$ then $O_K$ is the integral closure of $\Bbb{Z}$ in $K$. For a finite extension $L/\Bbb{Q}(\pi)$ then you can (and it is often done in algebraic geometry) look at the integral closure of $\Bbb{Q}[\pi]$ in $L$. It will be a Dedekind domain too, because $\Bbb{Q}[\pi]$ is. $\Bbb{Z}[\pi]$ is integrally closed but not a Dedekind domain, it and its integral closure in $L$ are more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you also apply this definition of $O_K$ to transcendental extensions like $\mathbb{Q} (\pi) / \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An integer in a number field of degree $n$ is defined as a root of some
> polynomial $X^n+a_1X^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.
> But as the degree of a
> transcendental extension is infinite, it seems to me that this
> definition does not seem viable for these field.

This is imprecise. An algebraic integer can be defined without any reference to a particular number field: an algebraic integer is simply a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients and leading coefficient $1$, of any degree. You can view the set $\mathcal{O}$ of algebraic integers inside the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ or a fixed algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}$. It turns out to be a ring: the sum and product of algebraic integers is an algebraic integer.

Given a field $K/\mathbb{Q}$, the ring of integers of $K$ is simply the intersection $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathcal{O} \cap K$. Once again, there's nothing in this definition that compels $K/\mathbb{Q}$ to be finite, although in Algebraic Number Theory we naturally tend to focus on number fields. For example, if $K = \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ then $\mathcal{O} \cap K = \mathbb{Z}$, simply because $\mathcal{O} \subset \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ while $\mathbb{Q}(\pi) \cap \overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{Q}$. You may have something else in mind when you speak of "transcendental integers", but the direct application of the usual definition of algebraic integers to the case of purely transcendental extensions does not yield anything new.

Transcendental field extensions are studied from many different perspectives: function fields play a central role throughout algebraic geometry, for example. Specifically for transcendental numbers inside $\mathbb{C}$, you may be interested in the field of Transcendental Number Theory, for example in Alan Baker's classic [monograph](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052139791X).

Comment: Your analysis of the transcendental integers according to the usual definition is actually simpler that I initially thought and well written. Thanks a lot for your answer!